# File Path on my NAS changing on Reboot

Tags: macos, network, finder, hard-drive, nas

Hey guys thanks in advance I can't find help for this anywhere outside of an old thread mentioning mDNSresponder causing the problem needing to be replaced with DiscoveryD.

They only recommend updating from Yosemite but I'm already running El Capitan.

Some background:
I have a Seagate NAS I auto connect to on my Mac via the log in items.

I keep it accessible in my dock and the file path appears not to change
[image: Accessing via volumes]

However in my Torrent / Usenet clients the file path seems to increment everytime  the server disconnects / reconnects

Transmission

[image]

If I go to browse the previously mounted volumes booty-1 / booty-2 etc. are all just empty. Only the latest iteration contains my data and I have to choose these manually.

You can imagine how frustrating this must be! Would really appreciate whatever advice you can give, can't imagine I'm the first person to run up against this problem.

Answer (score 1):

- Unmount all volumes mounted on `/Volumes/booty-1`, `/Volumes/booty-2`, `/Volumes/booty-3` etc.
- `sudo rmdir /Volumes/booty-[1-9]`
- Reboot your Mac or restart your NAS, whatever is more convenient

Comment: Thanks for the followup, is going to my device, right clicking 'booty' and hitting 'Eject' the same as umounting the volumes? Outside of external applications I can't find booty-1 or 2 or 3 anywhere in the finder.

Comment: If they don't show up in Finder or by running `mount` in Terminal any longer, they are unmonted/ejected.